# rounding up to the nearest penny in have

Tags: rounding

alright heres my assignment question

Create a Java program called DrivingCost that prompts the user to enter the distance to drive, the fuel efficiency of the car in miles per gallon, and the price per gallon, and then displays the cost of the trip:

I am supposed to get the result $81.40 but I keep getting $81.39
How do I round up that penny?

Here's my code

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class DrivingCost
 {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.print("Enter the driving distance: ");
         double distance = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("Enter miles per gallon: ");
         double mpg = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("Enter price per gallon: ");
         double ppg = input.nextDouble();
         double cost = distance / mpg * ppg;

         System.out.println("The cost of driving is $" + (int)(cost * 100) / 100.0);
      }
 }
```

Comment: mpg is miles per gallon

Comment: ppg is price per gallon

Comment: What values are you entering? Rounding 81.399 is a very different proposition than rounding 91.395 or 81.390001

Comment: im entering 1000 for driving distance, 43 for miles per gallon, and 3.5 for price per gallon

Comment: @TheBlueDog: This is a valid question, as there is an actual sincere effort to solve the problem. Please be polite.

Comment: @neito: Stop adding information in comments, and [edit] your question instead to provide them there.

Comment: @neito If you need to explain things like the meaning of different variables, do so in your code rather than leaving a string of short comments.

Comment: @TheBlueDog dude I wrote the code I just can't figure out how to round that last part chill out.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DrivingCost
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the driving distance: ");
        double distance = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter miles per gallon: ");
        double mpg = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter price per gallon: ");
        double ppg = input.nextDouble();
        double cost = (distance / mpg) * ppg;
        input.close();
        NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        System.out.println("The cost of driving is " + df.format(cost));
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked but we haven't learned most of the methods you just used......so Idk, this is chapter 2 stuff so our coding is pretty primitive at this point. Thanks for showing me another way to do it though.

Comment: No problem. In any real world application I would use this method. Only difference is that one might do a switch statement on the Locale in the event that  multiple locales are required.